# VBA: How to choose files from a folder based on a precondition loop in same sub?

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and I am trying to automate a dashboard process for my team. The dashboard takes two raw data files, I call these raw data and OP. I created a sheet with macro where I paste the raw data and run the macro by help of button. It filters data based on column 'Market', and there are some 14 markets, start the loop and repeat for all 14. So raw data is one big file with all markets and OP are 14 specific to markets, these are too heavy files.

What I am trying to do is to pick the OP file from the folder for same market as that which the loop picking in raw data file. So trying to get 14 output files for each market.

I looked everywhere no solution. Any help will be a great help.

```
  'Initialize Values

  Dim wb_RawData As String
  Dim wb_MasterData As String
  Dim wb_Control As String
  Dim wb_OP As String
  Dim Tempsheet As String
  Dim MarketArray As Variant
  Dim MarketColumn As Integer
  Dim Lastrow As Long
  Dim ArrayLength As Integer
  Dim Workbook As String
  Dim StartTime As Double
  Dim EndTime As Double

  'Loop start time

  StartTime = Now
  wb_RawData = "RawData"
  wb_MasterData = "MasterData"
  wb_Control = "Control"
  wb_OP = "OP"
  MarketColumn = 5
  Workbook = Sheets(wb_MasterData).Cells(22, 4)

  Sheets(wb_RawData).Activate
  Sheets(wb_RawData).Cells(104, MarketColumn).Select
  Selection.End(xlUp).Select
  Lastrow = ActiveCell.row

  Sheets(wb_RawData).Range(Cells(2, MarketColumn), Cells(Lastrow, MarketColumn)).Select

  If Not Selection Is Nothing Then
    For Each Cell In Selection
      If (Cell <> "") And (InStr(Temp_Value, Cell) = 0) Then
        Temp_Value = Temp_Vaue & Cell & "|"
      End If
    Next Cell
  End If

  If Len(Temp_Value) > 0 Then Temp_Value = left(Temp_Value, Len(Temp_Value) - 1)
  MarketArray = Split(Temp_Value, "|")

  'Loop through every MarketCode
  ArrayLength = UBound(MarketArray)
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

And then it copy and past the raw data into raw data sheet.
The below code is manually picking the OP file, and copy pasting in the main  dashboard. But I want to automate this process.

```
'opening the raw data order profile dashboard
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & FIE_OP_RawData     

'selecting the section
Range("A1:I1").Select     
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select    
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select    
Selection.Copy    

'pasting in new dashboard
Windows(FIE_Model_Dashboard).Activate    
Sheets(OrderProfiles_Sheet_NewDashboard).Select    
Range("a1").Select    
ActiveSheet.Paste    

'Save Dashboard    
ChDir _    
Location_folder     
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _    
Location_folder & "Dashboard - Market " & MarketArray(i) & " - " & 
Run_Period & ".xlsb" _    
, FileFormat:=xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False    

'Close Dashboard    
ActiveWindow.Close
```

I wish to select same market specific OP file from folder that the loop picked from the raw data.

Comment: I don't understand you question. Which part is manual?

Comment: Please be more careful in your use of line continuation `_`. Code like this: `'Save Dashboard    
ChDir _    
Location_folder` is very difficult to read. Additionally, the underscore in the variable name is often considered a bad idea for readability - `locationFolder` or `LocationFolder` would be a better bet. Also using the line continuation between a named parameter and its value is difficult to read as well (`Filename:= _`). I know this isn't the question you asked, but making your code more readable helps everyone, including you.

Comment: I don't see any loop in your codes.

Comment: @newacc2240 My bad, not manually but I mean to say its picking the file directed in the code by its name. What I wish to do it to select the market specific file from the folder, the same market that is being picked in raw data sheet.  The following code is picking the named file :        'opening the raw data order profile dashboard
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & FIE_OP_RawData

Comment: @h2s04 Sorry but the code after "If Not Selection Is Nothing Then" until the last line of first section, is not the loop?  I am very new to VB and can be wrong. Although I also would like to mention that this loop doesn't seem to working and I don't know why, it simply pick the highest length country and never work for another country.

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @h2so4 `For Each Cell In Selection`